# Nuxt environment configurations in Azure App Service

Tags: nuxt.js, azure-appservice

I have Nuxt(2.15.2) application that is deployed to Azure App Service and `NODE_ENV` app setting is set to `development`. But when `process.env.NODE_ENV` is accessed value retrieved is `production`.

But other app settings are read properly from App Service configurations. The project is build using `nuxt build` and run using `nuxt start`.

I would like a way to change `process.env.NODE_ENV` value when deployed to Azure App Service.